# Chrome DevTools no longer sees remote device

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, adb, remote-debugging

This is on a Win10 machine.

I wanted to debug a web page on my mobile phone today. I connected my phone through a USB cable and enable remote debugging through USB. I opened DevTools on Chrome and under "Remote Devices" saw a red circle with the text "Pending Authentication".

I had no idea what that meant, so I wanted to reconnect the USB cable. Just a fraction of a second before I removed the cable, I saw the red circle change to green. When I reinserted the cable again, nothing appeared in DevTools. And now, no matter what I try, the device will no longer show up.

I've tried revoking all earlier authentications on my phone, restart the adb server. Nothing helps.

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

I had to turn of USB File Transer (had to switch it to "just charge this device").